# get data from POST action asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have data posted with my `<input type="submit" value ="submit">` which has the following format (checked with firebug)

```
Role1 true
Role1 false
Role1 true
Role1 false
Name1 "Name 1"
Name2 "Name2"
```

and in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetPostData(ArrayList data)
```

the issue is what kind of parameters should i put in the controller to be able to have some kind of data structure which gets filled up with the values sent by post? I don't want to use FormCollection. I can make some sort of a PostModel, but all these data is sent through hidden fields dynamically generated with jquery in most of the time so I cannot imagine how I can bind the postmodel with the fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you meant (as having Role1 four times seems a bit weird):

```
Role1 true
Role1 false
Role2 true
Role2 false
Name1 "Name 1"
Name2 "Name2"
```

You could use a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public bool Role1 { get; set; }
    public bool Role2 { get; set; }
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetPostData(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

And since I suspect you are doing checkboxes stuff (due to the double boolean value for each role as the CheckBox helper generates a hidden field), here's what I will suggest you:

Model:

```
public class RoleViewModel
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class EditRolesViewModel
{
    public RoleViewModel[] Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new EditRolesViewModel
        {
            Roles = new[]
            {
                new RoleViewModel { Name = "Role 1", IsSelected = true },
                new RoleViewModel { Name = "Role 2", IsSelected = false },
                new RoleViewModel { Name = "Role 3", IsSelected = true },
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(EditRolesViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model EditRolesViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Roles.Length; i++)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Roles[i].Name)
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Roles[i].IsSelected, Model.Roles[i].Name)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.Roles[i].IsSelected)
        </div>
    }
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

or even better, using an editor template which will be rendered for each role:

```
@model EditRolesViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Roles)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and the editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/RoleViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model RoleViewModel

<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IsSelected, Model.Name)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSelected)
</div>
```

Comment: Good thing of this is that you can add an extra field (for example, `Id`) to your ViewModel and then all you need is to update the custom editor (add a new hidden field.) Sweet.

Answer (score 0):

Like Darin suggested you should use a view model.

This way you can pass data from Controller to View and vice versa. This is highly convenient when you validate your view model, detect some kind of validation error (too low value for example) and then send all the data back to the view.

You can find good instructions about different ways to "move" data back and forth between client and server side.

[Use ViewData and Implement ViewModel Classes](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/nerddinner/use-viewdata-and-implement-viewmodel-classes)

[Views and ViewModels](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3)

**Update**

Problem is probably in the binding of the checkbox, so my links that I added might be too "generic".